# This Code can Throw an IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, locking, synchronized-block

```
void waitForSignal(){
    Object ob =new Object();

    synchronized (Thred.currentThread()) {
        try {
            ob.wait();
            ob.notify();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This Methods Throws an IllegalMonitorStateException. Can some one explain why so.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only invoke `wait` on the object that you have acquired lock on.

In your code, you have acquried lock on `Thread.currentThread()`, but you are invoking it on `ob`, which will throw `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

So, you should rather change your synchronized block to: -

```
synchronized (ob) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to synchronize on the object you are waiting:

```
synchronized (ob) {
        try {
            ob.wait();
            ob.notify();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If even you fixed your problem with IllegalMonitorException like

```
void waitForSignal() {
    Object ob = new Object();
    synchronized (ob) {
```

your code won't work. In your code each thread creates a new lock, invisible outside the method. No chance for other threads to notify waiting threads.